# React: Feed in Shopify Blog via fetch - not working?

Tags: reactjs, shopify

I have the following which I used successfully for feeds from Wordpress, but I cannot get it to do the same with Shopify.

I created a private App within shopify and placed the access token into the header - but all I get from the React side is:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/blogs/blog.atom' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

```
const mediumRssFeed = "https://example.com/blogs/blog.atom";
  const MAX_ARTICLES = 99;

  const [articles, setArticles] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadArticles = async () => {
      fetch(mediumRssFeed, { headers: {"X-Shopify-Access-Token": "XXX", Accept: "application/json" }, crossDomain: true })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((newArticles) => newArticles.slice(0, MAX_ARTICLES))
        .then((articles) => setArticles(articles))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    };
    loadArticles();
  }, [MAX_ARTICLES]);
```

How am I able to integrate the blogs from my Shopify store into React?

Comment: What API are you trying to use here? Storefront API or Admin API?

Comment: @DavidLazar the admin API

Comment: You understand you can never access the Admin API from a front-end App except via the App Proxy pattern assuming you install an App and listen for incoming calls from said proxy.